# Send Notification Email SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I have created a simple notification email that sends email 7 days before due date and it works fine (see attached). There is new requirement that the Workflow needs to send another email 1 day after due date. My question is do I need to create a separate WF or can I update the existing one?

[image]

Kind Regards

Comment: You can update the same workflow and write the conditional if statement which will trigger the email one day after the "Due Date".

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the else branch to send the second Email. First set the value of a new variable, lets say "2nd Date", right before the pause action. Then just repeat the pause and Email process after the Reminder Email part.

[image]